# i need to restart django server to make my app properly work

Tags: django, python-2.7, reddit, http-error

so i made a python script to grab images from a subreddit (from Imgur and imgur albums). i successfully done that (it returns img urls) and wanted to integrate it into django so i can deploy it online and let other people use it. when i started running the server at my machine, the images from subreddit loads flawlessly, but when i try another subreddit, it craps out on me (i'll post the exception at the end of the post). so i restart the django server, and same thing happen. the images loads without a hitch. but the second time i do it, it craps out on me. what gives?

Exception Type: siteError, which pretty much encompasses urllib2.HTTPError, urllib2.URLError, socket.error, socket.sslerror

since i'm a noob in all of this, i'm not sure what's going on. so anyone care to help me?

note: l also host the app on pythoneverywhere.com. same result.

Comment: Please post some code or more info about what's going on. It's impossible to help like this.

Comment: this code is rather long so i'll put it in pastebin:

Comment: this code is rather long so i'll put it in pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/8RRfX9TS <-img grabber.
http://pastebin.com/d7bEnQZC <-views.
http://pastebin.com/jth2C5Gd <-urls.
http://pastebin.com/AKLX2btT <-manage.
http://pastebin.com/hMuk0tsy <-settings.

Comment: i don't know what else i can tell you.

Comment: another thing. sometimes i get HTTP Error 404: Not Found before i restart the django server. after i did, everything went as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `global` in your `get_subreddit` function looks wrong to me.

```
reddit_url = 'http://reddit.com/r/'
def get_subreddit(name):
    global reddit_url
    reddit_url += name
```

Every time, you run that function, you append the value of `name` to a global `reddit_url`.

- It starts as `http://reddit.com/r/`
- run `get_subreddit("python")` and it changes to `http://reddit.com/r/python`
- run `get_subreddit("python")` again, and it changes to `http://reddit.com/r/pythonpython`
- at this point, the url is invalid, and you have to restart your server.

You probably want to change `get_subreddit` so that it returns a url, and fetch this url in your function.

```
def get_subreddit(name):
    return "http://reddit.com/r/" + name

# in your view
url = get_subreddit("python")
# now fetch url
```

There are probably other mistakes in your code as well. You can't really expect somebody on stack overflow to fix all the problems for you on a project of this size. The best thing you can do is learn some techniques for debugging your code yourself.

- Look at the full traceback, not just the final `SiteError`. See what line of your code the problem is occurring in.
- Add some logging or print statement, and try and work out why the `SiteError` is occurring.
- Are you trying to download the url that you think you are (as I explained above, I don't think you are, because of problems with your `get_subreddit` method).

Finally, I recommend you make sure that the site works on your dev machine before you move on to deploying it on python anywhere. Deploying can cause lots of headaches all by itself, so it's good to start with an app that's working before you start.

Good luck :)